# Solving two compound inequalities simultaneously

Tags: inequality

Is it even possible to solve this?

I'm trying to find the point where one ceiling function is less than another:

$\lceil \frac {q}{m_1} \rceil   <  \lceil \frac {q}{m_2} \rceil$

$K = \lceil \frac {q}{m_1} \rceil$

$L = \lceil \frac {q}{m_2} \rceil$

$ K-1 < \frac{Q}{m_1} <= K < L-1 < \frac{Q}{m_2} <= L$

Is there a way to isolate for $Q$, so that given $m_1$ and $m_2$ you can find the $Q$ in which $K$ < $L$ ?

**edit after comment**

$ K-1 < \frac{Q}{m_1} <= K < L >= \frac{Q}{m_2} > L-1$

Comment: I think in your last chain of inequalities you don't want the $<$ sign right between the $K$ and $L-1$ in the middle. Because it looks like you only want $K<L$ and with the extra $<$ there it looks like one wants also $K<L-1.$ Suggest keeping it as the definitions for $K$ and $L$ separately, then the statement $K<L$ by itself,

Comment: @coffeemath Good catch, see the new edit, does that not work?

Comment: thefoxrocks Yes now it works and is even all in one line. Should we assume $Q>0$? same question about $m_1,m_2.$ [In case all are positive there may be a natural restriction on the order between the $m_i$]

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, all positive. $m_2$ > $m_1$ if that helps as well.

Comment: thefoxrocks I've corrected and added some to my previous answer, which I deleted before and corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example: Suppose $m_1=5,m_2=4.$ Also put $f(q)=[q/5],\ g(q)=[q/4].$ Then on the interval $(4,5]$ we have $f(x)=1,g(x)=2.$ (I'm using $[x]$ for the ceiling here out of laziness.)

The two functions agree on the interval $(5,8].$ Then on $(8,10]$ we have $f(x)=2,g(x)=3.$ Things go on like this, the half open intervals on which $f(x)<g(x)$ doubling in length and starting at $4k,$ where $k=1,2,3,...$

**Major Edit:** The above example is a bit misleading. It does show that for some values of $m_i$ the values of $q$ at which the desired jump of at least 1 unit may be spread out into intervalues initially. However there is a simpler way to look at things. First note that we need to assume $m_1>m_2$ and not the other way around, since from $m_1<m_2$ would follow $q/m_1>q/m_2$ and this would imply for the ceilings that $[q/m_1] \ge [q/m_2]$ and one could not then have $K<L.$

Now the function $f(q)=q/m_1$ grows more slowly than $g(q)=q/m_2.$ So if we find the point where $f(q)+1=g(q)$, which is $$q_0=\frac{m_1m_2}{m_1-m_2},$$
then for all $q > q_0$ we will have $f(q)+1 < g(q),$ hence the ceiling of $f(q)$ is at least one less than the ceiling of $g(q).$ A few examples show this gap widens as $q$ increases.

Of course this may not pin down *exactly* where the desired behavior begins to happen since there may be a few values nearby which aren't captured on looking at the arguments to the ceiling functions.